# Friendship has expired. No option to renew

Tags: civilization-6

My friendship with the Kongo has expired.

I went to the diplomatic screen and the option to ask for friendship is not present. Only Make Deal.

Have tried waiting till the next turn thinking it was one of those things.

Comment: anyway. i hope this helps someone because i was scratching my head.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The friendship may have expired, however, I have an alliance with Kongo. This is like a higher level of friendship. So once the alliance expires, the friendship and or alliance options will show.

The option is not showing because I am in an alliance.

Alliance is like Best-Bestest-Friends and is a trade option. It is not a defence treaty.

Why it is in a different spot to declaring friendship, I don't know. *Should I exchange uranium for your alliance?*